# how do I avoid having two Alarms set (one by the application and one by boot?)

Tags: android

I have boot receiver class which is setting an alarm, as well as the main activity. Does it automatically identify duplicate alarms? If yes, how does it detect it, else how should I prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

When a device is shut down, all current alarms in the system are removed. That's why all alarm related applications register for a boot receiver.

So there's no need to worry about that specific issue, you should just register all your alarms when your boot receiver is called, and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the `requestCode` used in your alarm `PendingIntent` is the same the `AlarmManager` will delete and recreate the alarm and will not duplicate it.

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```